# How to add a lookup field to workflow custom task form?

Tags: designer-workflow, form, tasks

I'm trying to create a task in a workflow which collects data from user with sp designer 2010.
Some predefined available type for custom form fields single line of text, choice and such things.
I want to add a custom type which is a drop-down list, and fill it with a look up site column (look up in other lists in site ).

Is there any possibility to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done this by customize task form in Info path,I've created Custom Task form with `Start A Custom Task Process` action and in Task Setting , I've added a choice field to task form fields. after publish workflow, I've changed task form in info path and connect drop-down in task form to one of SharePoint list data source.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint OOTB doesn't have methods for doing this in SharePoint Designer.  The "official" way is to use InfoPath and Visual Studio to create a Visual Studio workflow with an InfoPath workflow form.

With that said, however, this blog post shows one way to hack around this in SharePoint Designer: http://generation12.wordpress.com/2009/03/12/using-lookup-fields-in-workflow-initiation-forms/

Comment: That's for Initiation form. I'm looking for a way too add a dropdown to Tasks when I'm Collecting Data From User.